# Debug Assertion Failed error Buffer != nullptr

Tags: c, pointers, struct, null, visual-studio-debugging

i have been given this function for my programing in c assignment
but every time i try and run it i get an [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmoC9.png)

```
int importWeatherDataFile(FILE* fp, struct WeatherRecord* data, int max)
{
    int recs = 0;

    if (fp != NULL)
    {
        while (recs < max &&
            fscanf(fp, "%d,%d,%lf,%c,%d,%15[^\n]\n",
                &data[recs].date.year, &data[recs].date.month,
                &data[recs].precipAmt, &data[recs].unit,
                &data[recs].location.regionCode,
                data[recs].location.name) == 6)
        {
            recs++;
        }
    }

    return recs;
}
```

i call the function in my main function

```
int main(void)
{
    int weatherCount;
    struct WeatherRecord data[MAX_RECORDS] = { {0} };
    
    FILE* fp = fopen("weatherdata.txt", "r");

    weatherCount = importWeatherDataFile(fp, data, MAX_RECORDS);

    menuMain(data,weatherCount);

    return 0;
}
```

as the code suggests i have a few structures which may be a part of the problem.

```
struct Date
{
    int year;
    int month;
};

struct Location
{
    int regionCode;
    char* name;
};

struct WeatherRecord
{
    struct Date date;
    double precipAmt;
    char unit;
    struct Location location;
};
```

help me please

Comment: What is `menuMain`? What is `MAX_RECORDS`? What is in the text file? Please provide complete code and input data as a [mre]. And what is the back trace when the error occurs? That is, what is the exact line of your code that triggers the error?

Comment: `char* name` that is a NULL pointer. Trying to write to it in the `fscanf` results in Undefined Behaviour. You need to change that to an array or dynamically allocate memory to assign to it.

Comment: You are not providing any memory for the `name` member of the `struct Location` structures.

Comment: thank you kaylum and Eric Postpischil that seemed to be the main issue